# grails domain id as int or Long

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi I have a domain class that I set as `int userID`. Will it affect when the auto number become very big that `User.findById()` throws error? If I change to Long now (people are already using the application) will it affect the `findById()`?

Answer (score 1):

`findById()` will work just fine.

The real problem will be when inserting new data into a table, if the id is auto-generated, it, most probably, will restart when reaching the max value which can result in duplicate ids, and hence, errors.

In general, is not that easy to alter the schema definition when the app is already in production and the DB is populated. And if you try to do that in Grails, you have the risk of losing information in the DB. So please, do a backup, before trying anything.